# Using Taylor Polynomial to Degree 5 to Approximate Machin's Formula for $\frac{\pi}{4}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, pi

CONTEXT: Uni question made up by lecturer

How would use the Taylor polynomial to degree 5 to approximate $4\arctan(\frac{1}{5})-\arctan(\frac{1}{239})$

Recall Machin's formula: $\frac{\pi}{4}=4\arctan(\frac{1}{5})-\arctan(\frac{1}{239})$ .

I tried to do this using a difference of $\arctan x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$, where I subbed $x=\frac{1}{5}$ and $x=\frac{1}{239}$ and multiplied the first sigma by $4$, but couldn't work out how to simplify two infinite sums into one.

I was left with:
$$4\arctan(\frac{1}{5})-\arctan(\frac{1}{239})=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{4(-1)^n}{5^{2n+1}(2n+1)}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{239^{2n+1}(2n+1)}$$

Comment: OK, now the question asks you to use Taylor polynomials of degree $5$.  So replace the $\infty$'s by $2$ (since $2 \cdot 2 + 1 = 5$).

Comment: @RobertIsrael So I'm left with $\frac{951}{1195}-\frac{54607801}{5119469625}+\frac{3119245057671}{12184551018734375}$?

Comment: That's pretty close to $\frac\pi4$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want a single sum, reduce to same denominator to get
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n  \left(4\times 239^{2 n+1}-5^{2 n+1}\right)}{(2 n+1)\,1195^{2n+1}}$$